# Databinding using ["string"] syntax in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, winrt-xaml

If I have

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged{
    public object this[string name] {
        get {
            PremiseProperty prop;
            if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out prop))
                return prop.Value;
            return null;
        }
        set {
            SetMember(name, value);
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

In code I can do

```
var f = new Foo();
f["Charlie"] = 42;
Debug.WriteLine(f["Charlie"]);
```

How do I access the 'property' "Charlie" in XAML?

It's not these:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=[Charlie]}"/> // hangs designer
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=["Charlie"]}"/> // bad syntax
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=['Charlie']}"/> // bad syntax
```

Comment: The 'hangs designer' example is correct. It turns out my designer was hung for some other reason (WSstore stopping?).  So nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting DataContext,
Try this (Updated):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [Charlie]}"/>
```

Comment: Nope, it's `<TextBlock Text="Binding [Charlie]}"`. Thanks though.